# VMFS disk cloning

Tags: vsphere, esxi, dd

I have a new SSD (256GB) where I got installed ESXi 6.7 (the usual bunch of standard partitions) + couple of VMFS volumes (20GB each) that contains two Linux flavors. Everything works. So, now I would like to have a backup copy of the system then I cloned the SSD into another identical SSD (in the future I wanted to have a file image .iso) but when I test the new cloned USB something is wrong. ESXi boots up and I do see the two VMFS partitions but they do not appear as datastores, they are not usable and the two virtual machines appear to be broken (most likely because of no datastore).

I do the copy, booting with a live linux and using dd:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda bs=512 conv=noerror, sync
```

of course sda and sdb are not in use when I clone, as Linux boots up from the USB.
Any idea why the exact copy delivered by dd does not work exactly the same original SSD? Is there any special settings to be used with dd?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why a bit by bit cloned copy does not show the same but eventually mounting manually (via ssh) the VMFS partitions makes the magic and the virtual machine works.